# SSRS on web is not connecting to my web pages in asp.net. Throw error "The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized."

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services

```
IReportServerCredentials irsc = new CustomReportCredentials("username", "password", "http://dominelink/Reports/browsedata/");  
 rptViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = irsc;
 string urlReportServer = "http://dominelink/ReportServer?%somedata-001%2fcandidates&rs:Command=Render&vendor_id=1&rc:Toolbar=false";  
         rptViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;   
rptViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri(urlReportServer);
```

i am accessing it from web and my website has other credential for database i am using which is required. how can i grab details from that web credentials.